# Setting a default content-type header while using @RequestBody

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

When using `@Requestbody`, I am not able to run the API without sending a content-type header with a value of `application/json`. I want a method to set this header by default whenever the controller is called.

I don't want to use `HttpRequest`. I have tried to set the `produces` and `consumes` parameter in `@RequestMapping`, but in vain. I noticed that without the header the user is not able to hit the API.

```
@ResponseBody
@PostMapping(value = "/1.0/{productType}/itinerary/create)
protected ResponseEntity<String> createIternary(@PathVariable final String productType, 
@RequestParam(name = "product-id", required = false, defaultValue = "-1") String productIdStr, 
@RequestParam Map<String, String> searchRequest) 
throws Exception {}
```

```
{
    "timestamp": 1568117108917,
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
    "message": "Content type 'text/plain' not supported",
    "path": "/local/1.0/ttd/itinerary/create"
}
//This is the error in Postman

{
    "timestamp":1568116888056,
    "status":415,
    "error":"Unsupported Media Type",
    "exception":
"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
    "message":"Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported", 
    "path":"/local/1.0/ttd/itinerary/create"
}
//This is the error in terminal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring dependends on `Content-Type` header to correctly handle the request.

If you want to customize it, you need to do it yourself, by writing some sort of request wrapper and / or a filter.

---

**UPDATE**

You'll need to create a class which `extends` from `HttpServletRequestWrapper` and a filter.

The `HttpServletRequestWrapper` can be used exactly for that. Sometimes you want to adjust the original request. With this wrapper, you can wrap the original request and override some methods to modify it's behaviour.

**ContentTypeRequestWrapper.java**

```
public class ContentTypeRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    public ContentTypeRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
    }

    @Override
    public String getContentType() {
        return "application/json";
    }

    @Override
    public String getHeader(String name) {
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("content-type")) {
            return "application/json";
        }

        return super.getHeader(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration <String> getHeaderNames() {
        List <String> headerNames = Collections.list(super.getHeaderNames());
        if (!headerNames.contains("content-type")) {
            headerNames.add("content-type");
            return Collections.enumeration(headerNames);
        }

        return super.getHeaderNames();
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration <String> getHeaders(String name) {
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("content-type")) {
            return Collections.enumeration(Collections.singletonList("application/json"));
        }

        return super.getHeaders(name);

    }

}
```

**ForcedApplicationJsonContentTypeFilter.java**

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ForcedApplicationJsonContentTypeFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException,
    ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(new ContentTypeRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) req), resp);
    }

}
```

Of course this is not the best way to do so. The way I wrote it, you're assuming that 100% of the incoming request to your API are in JSON format.

You'll probably need to adapt the `ContentTypeRequestWrapper` to do some validations like 'is Content-Type already set? Then don't override'.

Comment: can you please elaborate how a 'request wrapper' or 'filter' can be coded so that it takes the same content-type from every source.

Answer (score -1):

The `@PostRequest` annotation has both a `consumes` and `produces` property.  In this case you would want to use the `produces` property:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/1.0/{productType}/itinerary/create", produces = "application/json")
```